# ReactJS using 0 to access a nested JSon object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object

In ReactJS I have used Fetch() to get https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/M6E=F and am now trying to access the nested item that is stored in the json object called "actualData". Due to it using "0" in the path, I cannot find a way to drill down in the following line...

```
console.log(actualData.chart.result.0.meta.currency);
```

The code above errors because of the "0". How do I include that "0" to access the "currency" element under "meta"?

Comment: result is a array so `actualData.chart.result[0].meta.currency`

Comment: you are right. thank you. I tried a lot of methods in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json  but missed the fact it was telling me it was an array. if you want to post that as an answer I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result is a array, so you should access data by index

```
actualData.chart.result[0].meta.currency
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this:
`console.log(actualData.chart.result[0].meta.currency);`